# My FPS camera is going crazy what I should do to fix it? Also Warning C26451 Arithmetic overflow

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glut

**NOTE** I know that my plane and the cylinder are badly built but their purpose is just to have something to see on the screen. Considering (px,py,pz), the camera position, and (dx, dy, dz), the view direction.

**Important:** My camera should follow a structure similar to the one I implemented here, so I can't use glRotate, glTranslate everything has to be done manually, the imposition of my teacher sadly, And also I am using Visual Studio.

**FIX:** My translations are all ok now I fixed a thing in the case GLUT_KEY_LEFT and GLUT_KEY_RIGTH.

**Problem:** Now the remaning problem is in the `mouse_motion`, when I click with left mouse button and drag the mouse around the screen my camera changes it direction really fast and sometimes when I go up it faces down its strange and hard to describe XD.

**Warning:** Warning    C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2). class2  main.cpp    199 .
This is my the line that says `gluLookAt(px, py, pz, px+dx, py+dy, pz+dz, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);` How can I fix it?

**Camera:** I just want the motion of the mouse to allow me to define the direction I want to go and use the up, down, left, right keys to move.

```cpp
#include <math.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795

//For Camera
#define GlUT_KEY_UP 72
#define KEY_DOWN 80
#define KEY_LEFT 75
#define KEY_RIGHT 77

// angle of rotation for the camera direction
float angle = 0.0f;  //alpha
float angle1 = 0.0f; //beta
// actual vector representing the camera's direction
float dx = 0.0f;
float dy = 0.0f;
float dz = 1.0f;
// XZ position of the camera
float px = 0.0f;
float py = 0.0f;
float pz = 10.0f;
float speed = 1.0f;
float rotateSpeed = 0.0008f;

//For FPS
int timebase;
float frame;

void changeSize(int w, int h) {

    // Prevent a divide by zero, when window is too short
    // (you cant make a window with zero width).
    if(h == 0)
        h = 1;

    // compute window's aspect ratio 
    float ratio = w * 1.0 / h;

    // Set the projection matrix as current
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    // Load Identity Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();
    
    // Set the viewport to be the entire window
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    // Set perspective
    gluPerspective(45.0f ,ratio, 1.0f ,1000.0f);

    // return to the model view matrix mode
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

// Draw Figures

void drawAxis() {
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    // X axis in Red
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    // Y Axis in Green
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, -100.0f, 0.0f);
    // Z Axis in Blue
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -100.0f);
    glEnd();
}

void drawPlane(float width) {
    width/=2;

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);

    glColor3f(4.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glVertex3d(width, 0,width);
    glVertex3d(width, 0, -width);
    glVertex3d(-width, 0,-width);

    glColor3f(3.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    
    glVertex3d(width, 0, width);
    glVertex3d(-width, 0, -width);
    glVertex3d(-width, 0, width);
    
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    
    glVertex3d(width, 0, -width);
    glVertex3d(width, 0, width);
    glVertex3d(-width, 0, -width);
    
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    
    glVertex3d(-width, 0, -width);
    glVertex3d(width, 0, width);
    glVertex3d(-width, 0, width);

    glEnd();
}


void drawCylinder(float radius, float height, int slices) {
    float interval = 2 * PI / slices;
    float next_a, next_h;

    for (float a = 0; a < 2 * PI; a += interval) {
        next_a = a + interval;
        if (next_a > 2 * PI) {
            next_a = 2 * PI;
        }

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        //Top
        glColor3f(0.698f, 0.133f, 0.133f);

        glVertex3f(0.0f, height / 2, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(radius * sin(a), height / 2, radius * cos(a));
        glVertex3f(radius * sin(next_a), height / 2, radius * cos(next_a));

        //Bottom
        glColor3f(0.698f, 0.133f, 0.133f);

        glVertex3f(0.0f, -height / 2, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(radius * sin(next_a), -height / 2, radius * cos(next_a));
        glVertex3f(radius * sin(a), -height / 2, radius * cos(a));

        for (float h = -height / 2; h < height / 2; h += height) {
            next_h = h + height;
            if (next_h > height / 2) {
                next_h = height / 2;
            }
            //Walls
            glColor3f(1.0f, 0.271f, 0.0f);

            glVertex3f(radius * sin(next_a), next_h, radius * cos(next_a));
            glVertex3f(radius * sin(a), next_h, radius * cos(a));
            glVertex3f(radius * sin(next_a), h, radius * cos(next_a));

            glColor3f((a + 0.05) / (2 * PI), (a + 0.3) / (2 * PI), (h + height / 2) / height);

            glVertex3f(radius * sin(a), next_h, radius * cos(a));
            glVertex3f(radius * sin(a), h, radius * cos(a));
            glVertex3f(radius * sin(next_a), h, radius * cos(next_a));

        }
        glEnd();
    }
}


void renderScene(void) {

    // clear buffers
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set the camera
    glLoadIdentity();
    //FPS Camera
    gluLookAt(px, py, pz, px+dx, py+dy, pz+dz, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

// put the geometric transformations here


// put drawing instructions here
    drawAxis();
    drawPlane(4);
    drawCylinder(1,3,30);

    //FPS counter
    frame++;
    int final_time = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

    if (final_time - timebase > 1000) {
        int fps = frame * 1000.0f / (final_time - timebase);
        char title[(((sizeof fps) * CHAR_BIT) + 2) / 3 + 2];
        sprintf(title,"FPS: %d", fps);
        glutSetWindowTitle(title);
        timebase = final_time;
        frame = 0;
    }

    // End of frame
    glutSwapBuffers();

}

//FPS Camera

void move(int key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: {
        px -= (dz * speed);
        pz += (dx * speed);
        break;
    }
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT: {
        px += (dz * speed);
        pz -= (dx * speed);
        break;
    }
    case GLUT_KEY_UP: {
        px += (dx * speed);
        pz += (dz * speed);
        break;
    }
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN: {
        px -= (dx * speed);
        pz -= (dz * speed);
        break;
    }
    default: {
        break;
    }
}
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void mouse_motion(int x, int y) {
        float lx = x - 800;
        float ly = y - 800;
        angle = angle + lx * rotateSpeed;
        angle1 = angle1 + ly * rotateSpeed;
        dx = cos(angle1) * sin(angle);
        dy = sin(angle1);
        dz = cos(angle1) * cos(angle);
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

// init GLUT and the window
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(800,800);
    glutCreateWindow("CG");
    

// Required callback registry 
    glutIdleFunc(renderScene);
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutReshapeFunc(changeSize);
    //FPS 
    timebase = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);

// put here the registration of the keyboard callbacks

    glutSpecialFunc(move);
    glutMotionFunc(mouse_motion);
    //glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouse_motion);

//  OpenGL settings
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    
// enter GLUT's main cycle
    glutMainLoop();
    
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Are you adding to the wrong variables in you `GLUT_KEY_LEFT` handler?

Comment: I think so, if I go to the left my z will increment and my x will decrement and my y won't change

Comment: I asked because in your other 3 cases you're changing `pz` etc (position) but for LEFT you change `dz` (delta).

Comment: Maybe I don't even need to move on the y on `move` as this work should be done by the `mouse_motion`

Comment: Moving left should move according to the `right` vector which is defined by cross product of your `front` and `up` vector. Which means it will change x and z unless you are perfectly aligned with an axis. For example, looking at (1,0,1) or northeast, holding left should move you (-1,0,1) northwest. disclaimer that I'm lazy and didn't read your code sorry :)

Comment: I got it now @1201ProgramAlarm XD. TY and now I have other problems.